# Code doubles netsalary in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

please can anyone tell me why the code below does not sum amount from deduction table and then deduct from the amount sum in the attendance table to get net salary. Instead of summing and deducting it doubles the sum of the amount in attendance table before it applies the deduction, am most grateful.

```
select sum(attendance.amount) - max(deduction.amount) 
from attendance 
join deduction on attendance.staffid = deduction.staffid 
where attendance.staffid = some_staffid 
    and month(attendance.date) = some_month
    and month(deduction.date_approved) = some_month
```

Answer (score 0):

just a wild guess - you have 2 deduction records for each attendance => the join will duplicate the amounts from attendance table => the sum will sum these duplicated records

easy solution (but not very well performing i'm affraid) would be:

```
select sum(a) - max_d
from (
  select attendance.amount a, deduction.amount d, max(deduction.amount) max_d
  from attendance 
  join deduction on attendance.staffid = deduction.staffid 
  where attendance.staffid = some_staffid 
      and month(attendance.date) = some_month
      and month(deduction.date_approved) = some_month
)
where d = max_d
```

Comment: thanks a lot, pls could u explain "not very well performing".

Comment: well, if you have milions of records, it might take a while to finish ;))